# Edit user profile using FOS User Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using symfony 2 with FOSUserBundle, the problem is when adding a user the current user profile logged in will be replaced by the currently added user, then when I tried to edit other user profile, the only editable would be the currently logged in user, is there something wrong with the inherited function from FOSUserBundle? I want that when adding a user, the currently logged in user would not be change with what is being added, and also when I edit another user profile, the user account that I'm trying to edit would be edited, not the currently added user account.

Here are my codes from FOSUserBundle :

Registration Controller :
 // adding user

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)

    {

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */

        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');

        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */

        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */

        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');



        $user = $userManager->createUser();

        $user->setEnabled(true);



        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);



        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {

            return $event->getResponse();

        }



        $form = $formFactory->createForm();

        $form->setData($user);



        $form->handleRequest($request);



        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);



            $userManager->updateUser($user);



            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {   
                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
                $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Sucessfully Added');
                $url = $this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_viewUser');

                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            }



            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));



            return $response;

        }



        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(

            'form' => $form->createView(),

        ));

    }
```

Profile Controller :
//used for editing user profile

```
public function editAction(Request $request)

    {

        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {

            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');

        }



        /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */

        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');



        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);



        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {

            return $event->getResponse();

        }



        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */

        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');



        $form = $formFactory->createForm();

        $form->setData($user);



        $form->handleRequest($request);



        if ($form->isValid()) {

            /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */

            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');



            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);



            $userManager->updateUser($user);



            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {

                //$url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
                $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
                $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Successfully updated');
                $url = $this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_viewUser');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            }



            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));



            return $response;

        }



        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(

            'form' => $form->createView()

        ));

    }
```

Comment: Do you register an User while logged in?

Comment: yes, I add user when logged in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The registration event is fired in your method, this is why the newly created user is logged in automatically.

To avoid this comportment and keep the current user as logged in (don't authenticate the newly created user), remove the following line :

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);
```

This two lines too :

```
$event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);
```

And this line :

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

Now you are just creating a new user without telling FOSUserBundle you are in registration.

**Update**

For the edit part, you have to create a specific method to reproduces the comportment of the editProfile, but for a given user (not the authenticated user).

Try to use the following :

```
public function editUserAction($id)
{
    $user = $em->getRepository('YourBunde:User')->find($id);

    if (!is_object($user)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Successfully updated');
        $url = $this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_viewUser');
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

And the route :

```
security_edit_profile:
    path:     /users/{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: YourBundle:Security:editUser }
```

Comment: thanks its working but how about the edit profile part?

Comment: how about the edit profile, how can i make it worked that whenever I clicked a user it must be the user to be edited and not the currently logged in?

Comment: I've added the changes.

Comment: its working that when I click a specific user it redirect to edit page with its corresponding info, but when  start to edit its profile,it not working as expected, because what I want is for example, I just want to edit the user's username, and save it, what it gives is that, it will give me a validation saying that the user's email for example is already used, how can we do this

Comment: You ask too much questions in one. You should open another, and before look at the FormFactoryInterface used for createForm. I know you can handle the form as a partial update (PATCH) but you have to find how in the class. Now you have all informations in your hands, just customise the edit method according to your need, it's no more specific to FOSUB, only part of Symfony form building/handling

Comment: Create your own form with the fields you want and use it instead of use the fosuser form.factory, see Form Type in symfony2

Comment: a little ungrateful that you do not accept the answer that solve your problem ...

Comment: how to edit user that is not the currently logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Remove from the RegisterAction:

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

Comment: how about the edit profile, how can i make it worked that whenever I clicked a user it must be the user to be edited and not the currently logged in?